# Is React Native's Keyboard's removeListener function required?

Tags: react-native

The example code for React Native's keyboard has `addListener` and `removeListener` functions:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", _keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", _keyboardDidHide);

    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidShow", _keyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidHide", _keyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, []);

  const _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    alert("Keyboard Shown");
  };

  const _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    alert("Keyboard Hidden");
  };
```

Is this code equivalent or will there be a memory leak from not cleaning up the listener?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => alert("Keyboard Shown");
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => alert("Keyboard Hidden");
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, there will be a memory leak from not cleaning up the listener. It's a good practice to clean-up the functions and remove listeners on component destroy

[Example here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard)